# Finds the destination point given a starting point, bearing and distance in minutes

Tags: coordinates, gis, geospatial

I need to find the formula to calculate the new coordinates starting from the coordinates of a place and adding a certain number of minutes in a direction.
e.g calculate the new coordinates starting from the coordinates of Rome and adding 2 degrees South-East. I found this calculator online:
http://www.geomidpoint.com/destination/
but the distance is in Km or miles, I need to use minutes instead.
Thank you in advance for your precious help!
Monica

Comment: Not clear. The bearing is in angular units (degrees, minutes, seconds, or decimal degrees), but you still need a distance in linear units.

Comment: This link section should help you with the formula you're looking for. [Destination point given distance and bearing from start point](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html)